# Drag and Drop Folder in Uploadify File Upload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using UPLOADIFY file upload for uploading multiple files and binding it in data list.

In this process i have to click on uploadify btn, then select all the image..

what i want is.. I have to drag the folder so all images which is in that folder and in sub folder get uploaded automatically..

How its possible to drag and drop the folder and upload the image through uploadify

Comment: nothing much, just I used uploadify for uploading the multiple image, nothing else, I am not getting the clue that how could I upload images by drag and drop.. just now I got a link for uploading image though it lets see. http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload is the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link is help full the my above question..

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

this code will not work on IE rest it will work fine on all browser. as the example is showing

thank you